# CocoaDialog text box displaying first line

Tags: macos, cocoa, bash, dialog, zenity

I'm trying to add the output of a script to a CocoaDialog textbox - problem is - it's only printing the first line....

For example - Please see below:

```
$ cat TEST.txt 
i
am
legend
$ /Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog textbox --debug --text `while read line; do echo $line; done < TEST.txt` --button1 "Close"
```

After running this the output is just "i"

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `` `while read line; do echo $line; done < TEST.txt` `` with `` "`while read line; do echo $line; done < TEST.txt`" ``, or preferably `"$(<TEST.txt)"`.

`read` strips characters in `IFS` from the start and end of lines. `read` also interprets backslashes without `-r`. `echo $line` strips and collapses characters in `IFS`.

```
$ echo ' aa  a\\a'|while read l;do echo $l;done
aa a\a
$ echo ' aa  a\\a'|while read l;do echo "$l";done
aa  a\a
$ echo ' aa  a\\a'|while read -r l;do echo "$l";done
aa  a\\a
$ echo ' aa  a\\a'|while IFS= read -r l;do echo "$l";done
 aa  a\\a
```